# Problemas al validar valores unicos

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, tengo una tabla Juego con los siguientes parametros:

```
Schema::create('juegos', function (Blueprint $table){
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('numero')->unique();
    $table->string('nombre');
    $table->unsignedInteger('agrupacion_id');
    $table->foreign('agrupacion_id')->references('id')->on('agrupacions');
    $table->text('materiales');
    $table->text('organizacion');
    $table->text('desarrollo');
    $table->string('foto');
    $table->text('observaciones');
    $table->text('variantes');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Quiero crear un formulario para modificar los valores de la tabla, para lo cual tengo esto:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Modifique los datos del juego</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{$j->id}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="numero" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Código del juego</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="numero" type="number" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('numero') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="numero" value="{{ $j->numero }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('numero'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('numero') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="nombre" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Nombre del juego</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="nombre" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('nombre') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="nombre" value="{{ $j->nombre }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('nombre'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('nombre') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="agrupacion" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">¿Como se organizaran los equipos?</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <select id="agrupacion" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('agrupacion') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="agrupacion" required autofocus>
                                    @foreach($agrupaciones as $agrupar)
                                        <option value="{{$agrupar->id}}" {{($j->agrupacion_id == $agrupar->id) ? 'selected' : ''}}>{{$agrupar->nombre}}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>

                                @if ($errors->has('agrupacion'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('agrupacion') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="materiales" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Materiales que se utilizaran en el juego</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <textarea id="materiales" name="materiales">{{ $j->materiales }}</textarea>

                                @if ($errors->has('materiales'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('materiales') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="organizacion" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Como se organizara el juego</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <textarea id="organizacion" name="organizacion">{{ $j->organizacion }}</textarea>

                                @if ($errors->has('organizacion'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('organizacion') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="desarrollo" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Desarrollo del juego</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <textarea id="desarrollo" name="desarrollo">{{ $j->desarrollo }}</textarea>

                                @if ($errors->has('desarrollo'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('desarrollo') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="observaciones" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Reglas y observaciones</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <textarea id="observaciones" name="observaciones">{{ $j->observaciones }}</textarea>

                                @if ($errors->has('observaciones'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('observaciones') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="Variantes" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Variantes</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <textarea id="variantes" name="variantes">{{ $j->variantes }}</textarea>

                                @if ($errors->has('variantes'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('variantes') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <hr>

                        <div style="margin-left: 35%;">
                            <b><i><u>Habilidades requeridas:</u></i></b><br><br>
                            @foreach($contenidos as $contenido)
                                <input type="checkbox" name="capacidad[]" value="{{$contenido->id}}" @if (old('capacidad[$contenido->id]') == "1") checked @endif> {{$contenido->nombre}}<br>
                            @endforeach
                        </div>

                        <hr>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="foto" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Nueva imagen (si es que la quiere modificar)</label>

                            <div class="col-md-7">
                                <input id="foto" type="file" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('foto') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="foto" />

                                @if ($errors->has('foto'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('foto') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Modificar Juego
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Y esto pasa por el siguiente validador:

```
public function rules(){
    return[
        'numero'=>'required|integer|min:0|unique:juegos',
        'nombre'=>'required',
        'materiales'=>'required',
        'organizacion'=>'required',
        'desarrollo'=>'required',
        'observaciones'=>'required'
    ];
}
```

Y en el parametro `numero` es donde viene mi problema, en el validador he pedido que si  el número del juego es detectado en la BBDD de error, pero eso significa que si modifico un juego pero no le cambio su número original, me dara error. Tendria que hacer que en caso de coincidencia compruebe si su número coincide con el del antes del cambio `$j` y de ser así que me lo de por válido.

Más datos: Probe a modificar esto en las normas de validación:

```
'numero'=>'required|integer|min:0|unique:juegos,numero',
```

Se supone que así esta más correcto el validador, aunque de momento mi problema persiste.

Aqui esta el código del controlador:

```
public function cambiar(Juego $j, CambioJuegoRequest $request){
    $enl=$j->enlaces;
    foreach($enl as $e)
        $e->delete();
    if(!empty($request->foto)){
        $j->limpiarImagen();
        $foto=str_random(30).'+'.$request->file('foto')->getClientOriginalName();
        $request->file('foto')->move('storage',$foto);
        $j->foto=$foto;
    }

    $j->numero=$request->numero;
    $j->agrupacion_id=$request->agrupacion;
    $j->nombre=$request->nombre;
    $j->materiales=$request->materiales;
    $j->organizacion=$request->organizacion;
    $j->desarrollo=$request->desarrollo;
    $j->observaciones=$request->observaciones;
    $j->variantes=$request->variantes;

    $j->save();

    foreach ($request->capacidad as $capa)
        Enlace::create([
            'juego_id'=>$j->id,
            'contenido_id'=>$capa
        ]);

    return back()->with('message',['success','Juego modificado exitosamente.']);
}
```

Comment: Si pones 'numero' => 'unique:juegos,id' lo que logras es que solo de error si el numero que tenga coincide con el id, algo ke me parece ke no es lo ke esperas. En realidad como lo tenias antes es como debe ser ya que lo ke deseas es ke no se repitan registros con el mismo valor del numero

Comment: Si me pones el codigo de tu controladora en la accion de editar puedo ponerte la respuesta ke necesitas

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas Gracias por indicarme el fallo. Lo he modificado y ya he incluido la función en el controlador.

Comment: Perdón pero no me queda claro que tiene que hacer la validacion, podrías explicarlo un poco mejor?

Comment: Y agrega el código de CambioJuegoRequest

Comment: Cuando editas y tienes el mismo numero la validacion salta pk esta viendo ke hay 2 registros con el mismo valor en un campo unico, por eso debes verificar si el error es ese lo remueves

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo haber entendido tu consulta, podes lograr lo que estas queriendo hacer agregando una custom Rule y luego aplicando esa Regla en la validación del Form Request:

**1. Crear la Regla**

```
php artisan make:rule CustomRule
```

**2. Editar la regla creada en app/Rules**

```
namespace App\Rules;
namespace App\Juego; //suponiendo que en esa carpeta esta la clase Juego

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class CustomRule implements Rule
{

    protected $juegoId;

    //va a recibir el id del juego cuando la llamamos para poder hace el chequeo
    public function __construct($id)
    {
        $this->juegoId = $id
    }

    //Acá haces la validación, (creo que esta es la que queres hacer).
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        $juego = Juego::find($this->juegoId);

        if(juego)
            return juego->numero == $value;
        else
            return true;
    }

    public function message()
    {
        return 'El campo :attribute no coincide';
    }
}
```

**3. Le agregaria un input type hidden con el id del juego al formulario para luego poder saber a que juego se refiere para la validacion**

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$j->id}}">
```

**4. Aplicas esta regla en la validación del campo y le pasas el id te que llega en el Request por el input type hidden agregado en el paso anterior**

```
public function rules(){
    return[
        'numero'=> ['required', 'integer', 'min:0', new CustomRule($this->request->input('id')],
        'nombre'=>'required',
        'materiales'=>'required',
        'organizacion'=>'required',
        'desarrollo'=>'required',
        'observaciones'=>'required'
    ];
}
```

No esta 100% testeado, pero creo que debería funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer que el validador devuelva unas reglas u otras en función del método que recibes:

```
public function rules()
    {
        if (\Request::isMethod('put')) {
            return [
                'numero' => 'required|integer|min:0|unique:juegos,numero',
                'nombre' => 'required',
                'materiales' => 'required',
                'organizacion' => 'required',
                'desarrollo' => 'required',
                'observaciones' => 'required'
            ];
        } else {
            return [
                'nombre' => 'required',
                'materiales' => 'required',
                'organizacion' => 'required',
                'desarrollo' => 'required',
                'observaciones' => 'required'
            ];
        }
    }
```

Luego puedes complicarlo todo lo que quieras.